# Instagram page is not opening pixel 7a for my app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, instagram

I am using the Instagram button which takes you to the Instagram page on the Instagram app. It's working fine in pixel 6 but it does not do anything on pixel7a.

In Android Manifest file using the below lines

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.instagram.android" />
</queries>
```

Code to open page

```
val intent = newInstagramProfileIntent(url)
    intent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.let {
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

where newInstagramProfileIntent is as below

```
fun Context.newInstagramProfileIntent(urlLink: String): Intent {
    val pm = packageManager
    var url = urlLink
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    try {
        if (pm.getPackageInfo("com.instagram.android", 0) != null) {
            if (url.endsWith("/")) {
                url = url.substring(0, url.length - 1)
            }
            val username = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
            intent.data = Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/_u/$username")
            intent.`package` = "com.instagram.android"
            return intent
        }
    } catch (ignored: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
    }

    intent.data = Uri.parse(url)
    return intent
}
```

When app is installed in mobile, button does not perform anything in pixel 7a only.

Both using Android 13

Comment: Please edit your post to include Android OS version running on each device.

Comment: I edited, fyi android 13 for both device